# Adding a comment character in most simple possible way

Tags: sed, comments

I want to search a file for a specific string and then place a comment at the beginning of that string. But I need an answer that avoids regex, global changes, and all the other fancy stuff.

I wrote this line:

```
sed -i.bak '/PermitRootLogin no/# PermitRootLogin no/' ./sshd_config
```

but I get an error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 21: comments don't accept any addresses

I assume the issue is that I need to escape the # character, but I'm not finding any resources on how to do that, or even mentioning it. I've tried various combinations of putting ^ or \ or \^ in front of the # but I'm jut not getting it right.

Please note I am intentionally repeating the text to be replaced. I would like the most simple possible solution to this question: how to replace "XYX" with "# XYZ" in the most obvious possible way.

Comment: I don't think "sed" and "avoid regex" are both achievable at the same time.

Comment: I am not trying to do general pattern matching. Just look for specific text and replace with specific text.

Comment: Did you forget `s` before `s/PermitRootLogin....`?

Comment: I think @mlt 's got it. `sed` error messages aren't particularly helpful, even for those of us that have been arm-wrestling it for , er, ah-hem... decades ;Good luck.

Comment: Apparently so. THANK YOU!

Comment: @mit Thats it. I think you want a simple substitution that has only a basic regex nothing fancy on the LHS. E.g. `sed 's/^PermitRootLogin no/# &/'`

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the comments by @mlt , you could try adding an s at the beginning your sed command. Straight from his comment:

```
s/PermitRootLogin....
```

I see that you said you're intentionally repeating the test to be replaced. If by that you mean, you want it to be the same, maybe consider grouping your matched text. I understand you may have meant that you just want it hand typed. Anyway, here is how to match the grouped text and add the comment character:

```
s/(PermitRootLogin)/# \1/
```

The parens indicated that the matched text should be consider a group, the \1 indicates that you want to put that matched group there.

I hope this was helpful. Happy coding! Leave a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you. Repeating the original text was above me when I wrote the question and I'm tryna learn it now.